Printing with Direct2D on Win10 in landscape prints blank page
I'm trying to print on Windows 10 using Direct2D. This works in portrait mode, however if specify landscape mode manually in the print dialog, all I get is a blank page. If OR in PD_RETURNDC to the PRINTDLG.Flags field and use GetDeviceCAPS(printDlg.hDC, PHYSICALWIDTH) on the DC that PrintDlg returns, it reports the correct width (also the correct height for PHYSICALHEIGHT) in both portrait and landscape. (Note that, obviously, I'm not printing using the GDI hDC, as you can't do that with Direct2D). DEVMODE.dmOrientation correctly reports DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE.
It works in both portrait and landscape if I print to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer. However, I do need to set the scaling to 600 / 96, which seems odd. (600 is the dpi reported, and 96 is the dpi Direct2D assumes, but I only need to do it for the print to PDF.) I have also tried adding large text at (-2in, -2in), (-2in, 0in), and (0in, -2in), one of which should be visible if I needed to rotate or something. Similarly, I have tried translating by (-2in, -2in). I have also tried rotating 45 deg and -45 deg, in hopes of seeing something, but I still get a blank page. So I don't think the problem is the drawing code, because it works when printing to PDF, and I should see something if my scaling or rotation were incorrect on the printer. Notepad++ prints landscape fine if I select it from the dialog, so it does not seem like the problem is the printer driver. The printer I'm using is a Brother HL-L2370DW laser printer.
I also tried setting dmOrientation to DMORIENT_PORTRAIT after the call to PrintDlg() and after I get the page size from the hDC but before the call to PTConvertDevModeToPrintTicket(), and this prints what I would expect if the code expects landscape but the printer used portrait.
